# What is the follow chart of login with vk.com

Tags: vk

I need only to know the steps as 1- 2- 3- for how to program a system to log users in with their VK.com account.

I searched for all questions relating this, and Googled it too for any tutorial and that was totally in vain expect the docs which doesn't state the steps.

Answer (score 0):

I use library https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib
Vk OAuth is similar to Google.

1. Create app https://vk.com/editapp?act=create
2. Load OAuth library
3. Paste credentials
4. Auth with vk.com
5. Run request '/users.get' to get user info